# Histogram in the same worksheet using perl

Tags: excel, perl, charts, histogram

im trying to plot histogram on the same worksheet as the table of data. Below is the perl script im using. The problem i faced here is multiple chart worksheets are created but i want the chart to be in the same worksheet as the data table.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);

{
    my $output_fn = 'result.xlsx';
    my $input_fn = 'accuracy_final.txt.gz';
    my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( $output_fn );
    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
    my $zip = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new( $input_fn )
      or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";
 
    my $col = 0;
    my $row = 1;
    while (!$zip->eof()) {
        my $line = $zip->getline();
        chomp($line);
        next if $line !~ /\S/;  # skip empty lines
        my $value = $line;
        $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $value );
        $row++;
        
        # Add a worksheet chart.
        my $chart = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'line' );
 
        # Configure the chart.
        $chart->add_series(
            values => '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5000',
        );    
    }
    $workbook->close();
}
```

Expected output is as shown below:

[image]

Output Im getting:

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example of the input data file. That will make it easier for us to try reproduce. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: *"i want the chart to be in the same worksheet as the data table"* : You are only creating a single worksheet. Please clarify.

Comment: I have edited my post with the expected output and the input data file is just a coloumn of values in text file.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that does not illustrate the problem you have

Comment: I edited the problem i am facing.

Comment: Seems like you should put the `add_chart()` outside the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me. You need to use the [`insert_chart()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#insert_chart(-$row,-$col,-$chart,-%7B-%25options-%7D-)) method to add the chart to the sheet. Also set the `embedded` option of the chart as described in the documentation:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);

{
    my $output_fn = 'result.xlsx';
    my $input_fn = 'input.txt.gz';
    my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( $output_fn );
    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
    my $chart = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'line', embedded => 1 );
    my $zip = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new( $input_fn )
      or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";

    my $col = 0;
    my $row = 1;
    while (!$zip->eof()) {
        my $line = $zip->getline();
        chomp($line);
        next if $line !~ /\S/;  # skip empty lines
        my $value = $line;
        $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $value );
        $row++;

    }
    # Configure the chart.
    $chart->add_series(
        values => '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6',
    );
    $worksheet->insert_chart( 'B7', $chart );
    $workbook->close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: may I know how do we plot histogram? As shown above, a line graph is plotted.